# property missing in returned json response / javascript

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Im working in React on some weather widget which displays temp and rain forecast. Im fetching data from OpenWeather and my json response looks like:

```
//rainy day
0:{
  main: {
    temp:10}
  rain: {
    3h: 1000}
}
//sunny day
1:{
  main: {
    temp:10}
}
```

the problem is **rain.3h** property appears in returned response only when it has some data, otherwise its missing. My request looks like:

```
async getForecast(term) {
  const forecastUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=" + term + "&appid=" + apiKey + "&lang=us&units=metric&cnt=16";
  try {
    let response = await fetch(forecastUrl);
    if (response.ok) {
      let jsonResponse = await response.json();
      let forecast = jsonResponse.list.map(
        day => {
          return {
            temp: day.main.temp,
            rain: day.rain["3h"], // can't map missed property
          }
        }
      )
      return (forecast);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

And Im getting error
TypeError: Cannot read property '3h' of undefined.
How may I add default rain:0 when the property is missing from response

Comment: Hi! Your JSON definitely doesn't look like that, because keys need to be quoted. Can you please post the _exact_ JSON response?

Comment: yes that was just a shortened version. exact one is https://www.screencast.com/t/DX8fMtzqNtD6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a check using  ternary operator

```
 let forecast = jsonResponse.list.map(
        day => {
          return {
            temp: day.main.temp,
            rain: day.rain?day.rain["3h"] : ''
          }
        }
      )
```

Comment: This is the [*conditional operator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). There is no null-coalescing operator (yet) in JavaScript.

Comment: Strictly speaking, that's a `ternary operator`

Comment: @lascort yeah sorry

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether the property exists or not

```
var obj = {};
obj.temp = day.main.temp;

if (day.hasOwnProperty("rain") && day.rain.hasOwnProperty("3h"))
  obj.rain = day.rain["3h"];

return obj;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use assignment with double ampersand "&&":

```
let forecast = jsonResponse.list.map(
  day => {
    return {
      temp: day.main.temp,
      rain: day.rain && day.rain["3h"] || 0
    }
  }
)
```

This works because if day.rain is undefined then the second part of the boolean expression will not be evaluated, avoiding the cannot read property of undefined error, and the value from the OR will be used for default assignment.